# No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.time.LocalDate'

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

We have written liquibase changelog to generate tables and using spring data hibernate support to map with entities.

But when I try to insert User with json payload. I am getting following exception.

*jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.time.LocalDate'. Check configuration for 'birthdate'
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:116)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: *.

My change log.
`<column name="birthdate" type="date 'yyyy-MM-dd'"> <constraints nullable="false"/> </column>`

Hibernate Mapping is.

```
`@Column(name = "birthdate", nullable = false)
private LocalDate birthdate;`
```

What is this issue and how to resolve it?

I try to do a api call to save this user. In that point I am getting above exception.

Comment: Remove the pattern from the changelog.

Comment: @M.Deinum Removed but not working

Comment: Did you add an `@Pattern` to a `LocalDate` field as that won't work (as the expection shows).

Comment: @M.Deinum This is only it.
@Column(name = "birthdate", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthdate;

Comment: @M.Deinum I fixed this one just by removing pattern

Comment: Which is what I suggested and you stated didn't work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by reverting in to API.yml by removing pattern from this.

```
    birthdate:
      type: string
      description: The date of birth in Cognito.
      format: date
      example: '1970-07-18'
```